# How to setup and use phpDocumentor step by step

Tags: php, phpdoc

How to setup and use phpDocumentor step by step?

I m trying using composer there are so many request for installation. can any one give me idea about phpDocumentor set and use in php.

tried $ composer require "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor:2.*"

getting below error

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.8.0 requires herrera-io/phar-update 1.0.3 -> satisfiable by herrera-io/phar-update[1.0.3].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.8.1 requires herrera-io/phar-update 1.0.3 -> satisfiable by herrera-io/phar-update[1.0.3].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.8.2 requires herrera-io/phar-update 1.0.3 -> satisfiable by herrera-io/phar-update[1.0.3].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.8.3 requires herrera-io/phar-update 1.0.3 -> satisfiable by herrera-io/phar-update[1.0.3].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.8.4 requires herrera-io/phar-update 1.0.3 -> satisfiable by herrera-io/phar-update[1.0.3].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.8.5 requires herrera-io/phar-update 1.0.3 -> satisfiable by herrera-io/phar-update[1.0.3].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.9.0 requires herrera-io/phar-update 1.0.3 -> satisfiable by herrera-io/phar-update[1.0.3].
    - herrera-io/phar-update 1.0.3 requires herrera-io/json 1.* -> satisfiable by herrera-io/json[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3].
    - herrera-io/json 1.0.3 requires justinrainbow/json-schema >=1.0,<2.0-dev -> satisfiable by justinrainbow/json-schema[1.1.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.5.0, 1.6.1, v1.6.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - herrera-io/json 1.0.2 requires justinrainbow/json-schema >=1.0,<2.0-dev -> satisfiable by justinrainbow/json-schema[1.1.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.5.0, 1.6.1, v1.6.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - herrera-io/json 1.0.1 requires justinrainbow/json-schema >=1.0,<2.0-dev -> satisfiable by justinrainbow/json-schema[1.1.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.5.0, 1.6.1, v1.6.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - herrera-io/json 1.0.0 requires justinrainbow/json-schema >=1.0,<2.0-dev -> satisfiable by justinrainbow/json-schema[1.1.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.5.0, 1.6.1, v1.6.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.3.1 requires dompdf/dompdf dev-master@dev -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[dev-master] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.3.0 requires dompdf/dompdf dev-master@dev -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[dev-master] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Conclusion: don't install phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.7.1
    - Conclusion: don't install phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.7.0
    - Conclusion: don't install phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.6.1
    - Conclusion: don't install phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.6.0
    - Conclusion: don't install phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.5.0
    - Conclusion: don't install phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.4.0
    - Conclusion: don't install phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.2.0
    - Conclusion: don't install phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.1.0
    - Conclusion: don't install phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.0.1
    - Conclusion: remove jms/serializer 1.11.0
    - Installation request for phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor 2.* -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor[v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.1.0, v2.2.0, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.2, v2.4.0, v2.5.0, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.2, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.9.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install jms/serializer 1.11.0
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.0.0 requires jms/serializer ~0.12 -> satisfiable by jms/serializer[0.12.0, 0.13.0, 0.14.0, 0.15.0, 0.16.0].
    - Can only install one of: jms/serializer[0.12.0, 1.11.0].
    - Can only install one of: jms/serializer[0.13.0, 1.11.0].
    - Can only install one of: jms/serializer[0.14.0, 1.11.0].
    - Can only install one of: jms/serializer[0.15.0, 1.11.0].
    - Can only install one of: jms/serializer[0.16.0, 1.11.0].
    - Installation request for jms/serializer (locked at 1.11.0) -> satisfiable by jms/serializer[1.11.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: It's as easy as running [single command](https://docs.phpdoc.org/getting-started/your-first-set-of-documentation.html#running-phpdocumentor). What's your problem?

Comment: There are [installation instructions using composer](https://docs.phpdoc.org/getting-started/installing.html#using-composer) available, basically you just `composer require "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor:2.*"`

Comment: I updated error message. any easy way without composer?

Comment: Right now, only the PHAR installation is recommended by the phpDocumentor team.  Some issues exist with both Composer and PEAR installation methods.  It's not yet clear if an upcoming 3.x release will address this.

Comment: @ashnazg Thanks for it.

Answer (score 6):

Try **PHAR** method. It will be easy.

You can download the latest PHAR file from http://www.phpdoc.org/phpDocumentor.phar.

The phar file can be used by simply invoking php and providing the phar file as a parameter:

```
$ php phpDocumentor.phar -d . -t docs/api
```

try it.